# Numerical methods to solve a continuity equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

What numerical methods can be used to study the initial value problem for the continuity equation where $ u = u(t, x) $

$$
u_t + \nabla\cdot(\boldsymbol b u) = 0, \qquad t \in [0,T], \quad x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
where $ \boldsymbol b = (0,\chi_{\{x_1 \le x_2\}}) $ and how can the solution be plotted using *Mathematica*?

- Here  $ \chi_{x_1 \le x_2} $ is the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Definition) of the set $ \{(x_1,x_2):x_1\le x_2\} $. And to fix ideas, we may take $ u(0,\cdot) = 1 $.

As a first step towards a complete solution, we ca take $ \chi_{x_1 \le x_2} $ as the characteristic function of the set $ \{(x_1,x_2):0 \le x_1\le x_2 \le 1\} $.

---

A related (more theoretical) question is on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328576/numerics-for-continuity-equation-with-sobolev-vector-field).

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html

Comment: Please express the equation in Mathematica format.

Comment: What is $\chi$?

Comment: Is it really necessary that $\chi$ as unbounded support? If $\chi$ were the characteristic function of a compact set, e.g. $ \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2  \leq 1 \}$, this would be much easier to do.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'd like to see the case of unbounded support. But as a first step, I'd be happy to see the compact support case too.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Riku Do you want to discuss this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.03867.pdf ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm not aware of that paper. What part is related to the example in this question?

Comment: @Riku Article title NON-UNIQUENESS FOR THE TRANSPORT EQUATION WITH SOBOLEV VECTOR FIELDS

Comment: @AlexTrounev I see. But does it deal with the specific example in this question?

Comment: @Riku No, they consider the incompressible flow with `Div[b,{x,y}]=0`  in your notation.

Comment: @Riku why did you say this is a continuity equation?

Answer (score 9):

To illustrate the problem, I will give an example that differs from the one proposed by Riku. But in this case, numerical instability is better seen. The result is similar to erosion. Perhaps geologists will like this.

```
b = {1, HeavisideTheta[x - y]}; L = 4; reg = 
 DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], MaxCellMeasure -> .01];
eq = D[u[t, x, y], t] + Div[b*u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;

ic = u[0, x, y] == Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
bc = {u[t, L, y] == 0, u[t, -L, y] == 0, u[t, x, L] == 0, 
   u[t, x, -L] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, {t, 0, 1}];

Table[Plot3D[sol[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}], {t, 0, 1, .1}]
```

[image: fig1]

This code has a message

```
NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help
```

This is confirmed by the data shown in Figure 1. Use the Sobolev vector field, as suggested by Riku. The following code has no messages, but the solution of the problem shown in Fig. 2 demonstrates similar erosion, as in Fig. 1.

```
b = {0, HeavisideTheta[x - y]}; L = 4; reg = 
 DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], MaxCellMeasure -> .01];
eq = D[u[t, x, y], t] + Div[b*u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;

ic = u[0, x, y] == Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
bc = {u[t, L, y] == 0, u[t, -L, y] == 0, u[t, x, L] == 0, 
   u[t, x, -L] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, {t, 0, 1}];

Table[Plot3D[sol[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}], {t, 0, 1, .1}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Finally, we use the initial data, as suggested by Riku. The following code has no messages, and the solution shown in Figure 3 has no features.

```
b = {0, HeavisideTheta[x - y]}; L = 4; reg = 
 DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], MaxCellMeasure -> .01];
eq = D[u[t, x, y], t] + Div[b*u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;

ic = u[0, x, y] == 1;
bc = {u[t, L, y] == 1, u[t, -L, y] == 1, u[t, x, L] == 1, 
   u[t, x, -L] == 1};
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, {t, 0, 1}];

Table[Plot3D[sol[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}], {t, 0, 1, .1}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

I add a numerical example for the solution that Vsevolod A. proposed. Equation has the form
$$u_t+\nabla .(u\vec {b})=0$$ with $b=(1,\sigma (x-y) )$ and $\sigma (s)=$`2*HeavisideTheta[s]-1`.

```
b = {1, 2*(-1/2 + HeavisideTheta[x - y])}; L = 4; reg = 
 DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], MaxCellMeasure -> .01];
eq = D[u[t, x, y], t] + Div[b*u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;

ic = u[0, x, y] == Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
bc = {u[t, L, y] == 0, u[t, -L, y] == 0, u[t, x, L] == 0, 
   u[t, x, -L] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, {t, 0, 1}];
```

[image: fig4]

Here we see numerical instability. Now we have to study how this instability arises from the solution in the form of the ODE system. First, we consider how the solution changes as `k` changes in approximate expression $\sigma =\frac {k(x-y)}{\sqrt {1+k^2(x-y)^2}}$

```
plot[p_] := 
 Block[{q = p}, b = {1, q*(x - y)/Sqrt[1 + (q*(x - y))^2]}; L = 4; 
   reg = DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], 
     MaxCellMeasure -> .01];
   eq = D[u[t, x, y], t] + Div[b*u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
   ic = u[0, x, y] == Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
   bc = {u[t, L, y] == 0, u[t, -L, y] == 0, u[t, x, L] == 0, 
     u[t, x, -L] == 0};
   sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, 
     u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {
       "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines",
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}}];
   Plot3D[sol[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"k = ", p}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}]] // Quiet
Table[plot[k], {k, 1, 11, 2}]
```

Here are the results for `t = 1` and different `k`
[image: fig5]

Comment: What version did you use? If it is Version 12, did you not get a message?

Comment: @user21 of course I got a message `NDSolveValue::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.` And this is shown in Figure 1.

Comment: Good, I think the message is correct. It's good that NDSolve warns about this since V12.

Comment: This is very interesting. Why do you think the erosion phenomenon happens? And why doesn't anything happen if the initial datum is constant?

Comment: Also, I've asked a related question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195776/numerical-methods-to-solve-an-ode-with-discontinuous-coefficients

Comment: @Riku It looks like erosion, but it is a numerical instability. The solution is stable if the Initial data satisfies some conditions.

Comment: "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2} is **never** needed. "InterpolationOrder" is only ever needed if there are more then one dependent variable and if at lest one one of the them has a lower interpolation order then the "MeshOrder". Please, please please delete this. People will copy it and have no idea what it does.

Comment: The `"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}` is redundant since you specified a first order mesh with a max cell measure. If you want a second order mesh use `ToElementMesh` everything else will not work and will not make difference. Something like `Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
reg = ToElementMesh[reg]`

Comment: `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> True` is not needed in this example.

Comment: `, Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2}}` is a tuning parameter, to speed up index 2 DAEs - I am not sure this does anything in this case.

Comment: @user21 You're right, we can delete all these options.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, thank you I appreciate that.

Comment: @AlexTrounev It is not clear to me if the erosion effect is loss of regularity of the initial data or some "numeric glitch". What do you think?

Comment: @Riku It does not matter what I think. We need a theorem here. Therefore, I gave a link to the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.03867.pdf

Comment: @AlexTrounev That article is about non-uniqueness issues though. But here we have a BV vector field, which should give uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you. This is very interesting. I'd be happy to see how this is related for the related problem for the ODE system: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195776/numerical-methods-to-solve-an-ode-with-discontinuous-coefficients

Answer (score 2):

This is a first order PDE which can be [reduced to a system of ODE](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahhwi/LTCC/sectionA-firstorder.pdf) (page 9) and integrated numerically.

I'm going to solve this:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})\cdot(u,\sigma(x-y))=0$.

Here $\sigma$ is some kind of smooth function with parameter than can give close-enough theta function. A substitution:

$\tilde{x}=x-y$

$\tilde{y}=y$

Gives

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}},\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{y}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}})\cdot(u,\sigma(\tilde{x}))$.

Or (without tildes)

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1-\sigma(x))+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\sigma(x)=u\sigma'(x)$

Which results in 4 ordinary differential equations.

$\frac{dt}{dr}=1$

$\frac{du}{dr}=u\sigma'(x)$

$\frac{dy}{dr}=\sigma(x)$

$\frac{dx}{dr}=1-\sigma(x)$

Starting from the last:

$\frac{dx}{1-\sigma(x)}=dr$

Choosing $\sigma(x)=\frac{\kappa x}{\sqrt{1+\kappa^2 x^2}}$

Gives the solution:

$\frac{2}{3 \kappa } \left(\kappa ^3 x^3+\kappa ^2 x^2 \sqrt{\kappa ^2 x^2+1}+\sqrt{\kappa ^2 x^2+1}+3 \kappa  x\right)=r+C_{1}$

Which mathematica can solve for $x(r)$, giving 4 different roots.

The first differential equation gives $t=r$ which gives $x(t)$.

The second and the third ones are expressed as integrals from analytical expresions:

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\sigma(x(t))$

$y=y_{0}+\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\sigma(x(t))dt$

$\frac{du}{dt}=u\sigma'(x(t))$

$u=u_{0}\exp(\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\sigma'(x(t))dt$

Where $u_{0}=F(y_{0},C_{1})$ is an arbitrary function determined by initial conditions.

The solution is thus:

$u=\exp(\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\sigma'(x(t))dt)\cdot F(y-\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\sigma(x(t))dt,\frac{2}{3 \kappa } \left(\kappa ^3 x^3+\kappa ^2 x^2 \sqrt{\kappa ^2 x^2+1}+\sqrt{\kappa ^2 x^2+1}+3 \kappa  x\right)-t)$

DON'T FORGET THAT TO SUBSTITUTE VARIABLES BACK

Comment: Could you write up an implementation of that technique in this case?

Comment: @Riku I suggest you to describe this method for your particular case (three ordinary  differential equations with `c1=(...)`, `c2=(...)` and add that to your question -  answers are pretty much guaranteed at this point.

Comment: @VsevolodA. This is not the case. There is a Sobolev vector field, so the "failure of uniqueness" is possible, as proved in the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.03867.pdf

Comment: @AlexTrounev how does non uniqueness affect my suggestion?

Comment: @VsevolodA. Perhaps there can not be used the inverse ﬂow map in a case of  the Sobolev vector field. Can you show how it works? Use my first example.

Comment: @AlexTrounev updated.

Comment: @Riku added an example.

Comment: @VsevolodA. Thanks for the example. But this is not relevant to our case. Take the equation $u_t+\nabla .(u\vec {b})=0$ with $b=(1,\sigma (x-y))$ and $\sigma (s)$=`HeavisideTheta[s]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev just take $\kappa$ large enough. You were ok with solving it with finite differences even though it contained dirac delta, I'm pretty sure my example is more legitimate for this equation.

Comment: @VsevolodA. Oh, now I see that there is a typo. Your equation is $u_t+\nabla .(u\vec {b})$ with $b=(1-\sigma, \sigma)$ and $\sigma = \sigma (x)$.This is an interesting example. I will add a numerical example to my post. +1

Comment: @AlexTrounev $b=(1,\sigma)$ in original coordinates.