# Numerical methods to solve an ODE with discontinuous coefficient

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

Consider the ODE 
$$\partial_t \Phi(t,x) = \mathbf b(\Phi(t,x)), \qquad t \in [0,T], \quad x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$
$$\Phi(0,x) = x, \quad x \in \mathbb R^2,$$
where $\mathbf b = (0,\chi_{\{x_1 \le x_2\}})$ and $ \chi_{\{x_1 \le x_2\}} $ is the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Definition) of the set $ \{(x_1,x_2):x_1\le x_2\} $.

What numerical methods can be used to solve this problem with Mathematica and handle the irregularity of the vector field $\mathbf b$? How can the solution be plotted?

As a first step towards a complete solution, we ca take $ \chi_{\{x_1 \le x_2\}} $ as the characteristic function of the set $ \{(x_1,x_2):0 \le x_1\le x_2 \le 1\} $.

---

In the related question
[Numerical methods to solve a continuity equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195547/numerical-methods-to-solve-a-continuity-equation), I've asked about the PDE version of this problem, which lead to an interesting answer.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html

Comment: `Consider the ODE` this looks like a PDE to me and not an ODE.

Comment: Have you tried anything?